# Assembly printing primes in some interval [a,b]

Tags: assembly, x86, primes

I have a problem with my program which should print primes in some interval [a,b]. It is not working correctly at the moment but I think I'm close. I think that maybe problem is with my stack operations and that's why it doesn't work. Am I right? Or maybe it is something else? Maybe someone had similiar problem to mine?

```
        MOV ax, [a]     ; ax = start of interval, a = start, b = end of interval
        MOV bx, 2       ; bx = 2 (for primes)
        petlap1:                ; loop for i = a; i <= b; i++
            CMP ax, [b] ;   a > b ? END
            JA  start
            MOV bx, 2   ;   starting from j = 2
            
            MOV bp, 1   ;   boolean flag: 1 - "i" is prime, 0 - "i" is not prime
            petlap2:            ;   loop for j = 2; j < i; j++
;               MOV dx, ax
;               SUB dx, 1
                CMP bx, ax  ;   i == j, then check if "i" is prime
                JE  czypierwsza
                
                XOR dx, dx
                MOV cx, ax  ;   save "i" to cx
                DIV bx          ; check for prime
                CMP dx, 0   ; "i" is not prime
                JE  niejest
                
                MOV ax, cx  ;   restore "i"
                ADD bx, 1   ;   increment "j"
                JMP petlap2 ;   continue "j" loop
            
            czypierwsza:    ;   is "i" prime? 
                    CMP bp, 1   ; 1 - it is, 0 - it is not
                    JE  konw        ; if it is then convert it to string for output
                    JMP zwieksz ;   if it is not then increase "i" and continue "i" loop
                    

            zwieksz:
                ADD ax, 1
                JMP petlap1

            niejest:    ;   "i" is not a prime, set bp flag to 0 and jump to check if it is prime (I know it is not the best way)
                MOV bp, 0
                JMP czypierwsza

            

            konw:   ;   convert "i" to string for further output
                MOV [i], ax ;   restore "i" to variable [i]
                XOR cx, cx  ;   cx = 0, I use cx for counting items on stack
                petstr:
                    
                    MOV bx, 10  ;   for division
                    XOR dx, dx  ;   dx = 0
                    DIV bx          ;   dx = digit, ax = quotient
                    PUSH    dx      ; push digit onto stack
                    INC cx          ; increment cx (how many items are on stack)
                    CMP ax, 0   ;   is this last digit of a number? if so go convert "i" to string for output
                    JE  dokonw
                    JMP petstr      ; if  not then continue pushing digits onto stack
                                    
                dokonw:
                    MOV si, 2       ;   si for writing to array of characters
                    JMP petkonw ; go write "i" to array

                petkonw:            ; write to array
                    CMP cx, 0   ;    is there any digit on the stack?
                    JE  wyp         ; there is none (I assume input is normal)
                    POP ax      ;   get digit from stack
                    ADD al, 48  ;   make it ASCII character
                    MOV [istr+si], al   ;    write it to an array
                    DEC cx              ; decrement cx 
                    INC si                      ; increment si to next position in an array
                    JMP petkonw         ; continue conversion
                    


            wyp:                                ;   print out prime
                MOV ah, 9
                MOV dx, ent         ; some enter for formatting
                INT 21h

                MOV ah, 9
                MOV dx, istr+2      ;   print out prime
                INT 21h
                MOV ax, [i]             ;   restore "i" for next iteration
                ADD ax, 1               ; increment it 
                JMP petlap1             ; start next iteration of "i" loop
```

It seems that for every interval `[a,b]`, my program prints "3" and loops for ever. For `[20, 40]`, it prints "31".

Comment: Please post answers with the "answer my own question" button, *not* as an edit to the question that turns it into a non-question.  I rolled back your edit because that's not how we do things on SO.  (You can still find the markdown source of your updated code and answer text in the revision history.)